# How do I create routes for a controller that does nothing with models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Still pretty new to Rails, so if I'm taking the completely wrong approach, please feel free to straiten me out.

How do I make routes.rb aware that there's a root controller full of actions that don't manipulate models, while preserving the route helper methods? I'd like it to respond to requests like these:

```
http://localhost/download
http://localhost/share
```

With route helpers like

```
download_app_path
share_path
```

but without static named routes like these:

```
match '/download' => 'site#download', :as => :download_app
match '/share' => 'site#share', :as => :share
```

from a SiteController that doesn't create, show, or otherwise manipulates models from my app.

I've tried using an approach like this, but it works without generating the route helpers ( naturally )

```
match '/:action', :controller => 'site'
```

I could theoretically do without the route helpers, but I think they're a bit easier to read than passing hashes of url options to link_to or form methods.

Is there a way to accomplish a more resourceful root controller, or is what I'm trying to do unconventional for Rails?

**Edit**

For clarity, here's what this SiteController class looks like:

```
class SiteController < ApplicationController
  def download
    @custom_options = { .. }
  end
  def share
    @custom_options = { .. }
  end
  def about
  end
end
```

Its purpose is to allow me to collect pages that don't interact with resources ( such as Users or Friendships ) into a single controller and maintain them all in one place. I'm trying to set this controller up as the application root controller - so all paths from this controller will be directly off the app host ( myapp.com/download )

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

routes and resources are not tied to models. it's just a RESTful convention. if you just want to use the index actions, in your example `download` and `share` could be done like

```
resouce :download, only: [:index]
resouce :share, only: [:index]
```

see all the examples in the guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

if you want to add the download and share functionality to some "resource" like, say a picture, then you would do something like:

```
resources :pictures do
  get 'download', :on => :member
  get 'share', :on => :member
end
```

a resource always has and endpoint `/pictures` for example. so if you want to have paths directly to your host, then you need to provide custom matchers in your routes like you did in your examples.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting I break out the 'download' and 'share' actions out of SiteController.rb and make them the index actions of their own distinct controllers, is that correct?

Also, the :only and :except options appear to only work on default routes; they don't expose the custom actions 'download' or 'share' to routes.rb when a request is incoming, leading me back to statically defining a route to get the desired path.

Comment: maybe i just don't understand what you are trying to do... is there some "resource" that you want to provide for downloading and sharing? then you could do a different approach.

Comment: No, there are no resources being interacted with or otherwise provided. Take a look at my edit, hopefully that will make it clear what SiteController's role is.